# Postgres is not returning any data when running Select query

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I'm running Postgres 9.22.2 and trying to run the following statement:

select * from table limit 100;

When I do this the command just hangs. ps output indicates that it's
    waiting:

```
postgres lookup [local] COPY  
postgres: lookup exomeSNP [local] SELECT waiting
```

I have a shell script which copies the data from CSV in at the regular time.

Following are the top 2 records of  pg_stat_activity

```
datname   |  pid  | state  |                                                                                                                              query                    

------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 lookup     | 22243 | active | copy cell_info(radio, mcc, net, area, cell, unit, lon, lat, range, samples, changeable, created, updated, average_signal) From '/data/cell-dup.cs
v' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER

 lookup     |  6529 | active | SELECT * FROM "public"."cell_info" WHERE "cell"=$1 and “net"=$4 ORDER BY "cell_info_id" LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I believe you have to wait till the COPY command finishes to be able to query the table. Anything else would defeat the purpose of a database.

Comment: @JimJones: `copy` just inserts into the table, that should not block a SELECT statement.

Comment: You should check what the SELECT is waiting for. `ps` is not the write tool for that, you need to check pg_locks and pg_stat_activity: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Answer (score 1):

A concurrent transaction is holding an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table.
Such locks are required by statements like `TRUNCATE`, `ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE INDEX`, to name a few.

You can find out which transaction that is by querying the `pg_locks` view.

`pg_stat_activity` will tell you what that concurrent transaction is doing. It is not necessarily the last statement in the transaction that caused the lock though.

Answer (score -1):

Bud you can debug from postgres activity log

```
 SELECT datname,pid,state,query FROM pg_stat_activity

Execute this query and find the state of query
```